# AWS Elastic Beanstalk selected Security Group update

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, network-security-groups

It seems something has changed with the Elastic Beanstalk Security Group handling, tonight at UTC 00:00 the webserver lost the connection with the RDS. 
I logged in to the EC2 console, everything looks good, the security group that belongs to the RDS instance has an Inbound rule that accepts MySql port to the security group that's been selected to the Elastic Beanstalk config.

When I set the RDS Security Group Inbound Rule to Anywhere the webserver and the RDS server can connect. When I add the rule back for the EB's security group the webserver can't connect to the RDS anymore.

This has been worked for years, nothing has changed, it just doesn't work anymore and I can't find the solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure no one has changed the EB's security group?

Comment: 100% sure, checked everything like 5 times cause it's unbelievable, also only I have access to the AWS

Comment: You can have a look at CloudTrial Event history. Maybe it will have some api calls which you don't recall or recognize?

Comment: I don't use any API call, I've checked the CloudTrial Events and nothing strange is there, only up and downscaling event as expected